# Nodejs http request not working

Tags: node.js, http, get

I have a piece of code that's supposed to do a http get request. The program exited successfully without error, but I didn't see any response and it didn't even go inside the callback function! At first I thought it's because http is asynchronous and put a large loop in the end but that didn't work either. Does anyone know this issue? Only the first console log sendHttpRequest and 444 gets printed. I also tried the http.get but it didn't work either.

```
function sendHttpRequest (url, callBack) {
    console.log("sendHttpRequest");
    //constrct options
    var options = {
        host: 'www.google.com',
        path: '/index.html',
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
           'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
    };

    http.get("http://www.google.com/index.html", function(res) {
        console.log("Got response: " + res.statusCode);
    });

    var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
        console.log("333");
        var output = '';
        console.log(options.host + ':' + res.statusCode);
        res.setEncoding('utf8');

        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
            console.log("DATATATAT!")
            output += chunk;
        });

        res.on('end', function () {
            console.log('222');
            var obj = JSON.parse(output);
            callBack(res.statusCode, obj);
        });
    });

    req.on('error', function (err) {
        console.log('error: ' + err.message);
    });

    req.end();
    console.log("444");
    }
}
```

Comment: Someone said that google doesn't have "/index.html", I removed it but still it didn't work. It just didn't even go inside the callback. No response.

Comment: How are you calling this? This has a few issues, but otherwise I see all of the `console.log`'s and the callback function is also called. You're also returning HTML, which `JSON.parse` will never work.

Comment: @making3 Hi, I wrapped this up as a module and called it from a grunt task, but somehow I only see the first console log and the last one, which is 444. Do I have to call async in either grunt or this module to wait for the response? Thanks! For the json part, originally I was going to parse a json so that wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @making3 Thanks to r3mus I figured out the problem. It's because grunt task terminated before I got the response from http request. Now I added async and callback to solve this problem! Thank you so much for your help too! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update**

The grunt task terminated before the OP received a response; adding `async` and a callback to the task fixed it.

---

If I take your code outside of the function and prepend `var http = require('http');` I get a response up until `222`, at which point it dies with `SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`. Which is actually dying because you're trying to parse an HTML response as JSON.

If you paste the entire script below and run it end to end, the console dies with:

```
undefined:1
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
    at Object.parse (native)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/Users/you/nodetest/tmp/test.js:31:28)
    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:120:20)
    at _stream_readable.js:896:16
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:599:11)
```

The script:

```
var http = require('http');

console.log("sendHttpRequest");
//constrct options
var options = {
    host: 'www.google.com',
    path: '/index.html',
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
       'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
};

http.get("http://www.google.com/index.html", function(res) {
    console.log("Got response: " + res.statusCode);
});

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
    console.log("333");
    var output = '';
    console.log(options.host + ':' + res.statusCode);
    res.setEncoding('utf8');

    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        console.log("DATATATAT!")
        output += chunk;
    });

    res.on('end', function () {
        console.log('222');
        // it's failing on the next line, because the output 
        // it's receiving from Google is HTML, not JSON. 
        // If you comment out this line and simply 
        // "console.log(output)" you'll see the HTML response.
        var obj = JSON.parse(output);
        callBack(res.statusCode, obj);
    });
});

req.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log('error: ' + err.message);
});

req.end();
console.log("444");
```

Comment: Hi, I wrapped this up as a module and called it from a grunt task, but somehow I only see the first console log and the last one, which is 444. Do I have to call async in either grunt or this module to wait for the response? Thanks! For the json part, originally I was going to parse a json so that wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: You're going to need to provide the wrapper in your question for me to actually determine that -- out of the box, you can see that this works, but if your grunt task is terminating before this finishes (and this is being run async) it would be a good bet that grunt isn't waiting for it to complete.

Comment: Turns out that you are right! The grunt task terminated before I got the response! I added async and callback to it and it worked. Thank you so much!! :)

Comment: Great stuff! Glad to hear it.