# Wait for JSON response data from POST request in nodejs (mocha test)

Tags: node.js, http, express, mocha.js

I'm aware that there are several questions related to mine, but I didn't find any of them useful:

- [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20479218/nodejs-http-request-not-working) doesn't apply to my case, I'm actually getting the answer, it's the contents that I can't get.
- [on this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29776412/nodejs-http-request-returns-undefined), on the other hand, the problem is a wrong handling of an asynchronous call, which is not my case
- [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24766481/nodejs-http-request-output), well, I really didn't fully understand this question
- And so on...

Then, I think this is a legitimate question. I'm actually performing some encryption in my server (express routing in node) through a post request:

```
app.post('/encrypt', encrypt);
```

Encrypt is doing:

```
function encrypt(req,res) {
    if(req.body.key && req.body.message) {
        var encryptedMessage = Encrypter.encrypt(req.body.key,req.body.message);

        return res.status(200).json({ message: encryptedMessage });
     }

     res.status(409).json({ message: 'the message could not be encrypted, no key found' });
    }
}
```

So, I tested this via console.log, and it's working. When the server receives the request, the encrypted message is being generated.

At the same time, I'm testing my thing with mocha and I'm doing it like so:

```
describe('# Here is where the fun starts ', function () {
  /**
   * Start and stop the server
   */
  before(function () {
    server.listen(port);
  });

  after(function () {
    server.close();
  });

  it('Requesting an encrypted message', function(done) {
    var postData = querystring.stringify({
      key : key,
      message : message
    });

    var options = {
      hostname: hostname,
      port: port,
      path: '/encrypt',
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Content-Length': postData.length
      }
    };

    var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
      res.statusCode.should.equal(200);
      var encryptedMessage = res.message;
      encryptedMessage.should.not.equal(message);
      done();
    });

    req.on('error', function(e) {
      //I'm aware should.fail doesn't work like this
      should.fail('problem with request: ' + e.message);
    });

    req.write(postData);
    req.end();
  });
});
```

So, whenever I execute the tests, it fails with `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'should' of undefined` because res.message does not exist.

None of the res.on (data, end, events is working, so I suppose the data should be available from there. First I had this:

```
var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
  res.statusCode.should.equal(200);
  var encryptedMessage;

  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
    encryptedMessage = chunk.message;
  });

  encryptedMessage.should.not.equal(message);
  done();
});
```

But res.on was never accessed (the console.log didn't show anything). I'm therefore a bit stuck here. I'm surely doing some basic stuff wrong, but I don't have a clue, and the many questions I found doesn't seem to apply to my case.

Weird enough, if I launch a test server and then I curl it
    curl --data "key=secret&message=veryimportantstuffiabsolutellyneedtoprotect" localhost:2409/encrypt

Curl justs waits ad aeternam.

Comment: Are you including body parser middleware? https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser

Comment: Well, I guess that's an answer... I'll do it tomorrow and accept your answer... Thanks !

Comment: Actually I was using it. `var bodyParser = require('body-parser');` `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));` `app.use(bodyParser.json());` All this before `app.use(passport.initialize());` So that's not the problem...

Comment: Looks like my encrypt should receive an extra parameter, and be calling next(). Unfortunately, this next is also writing the response headers, and then, when i'm calling, it throws the exception `Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I was doing it properly at the beginning, and the problem was indeed the same than in [the second question I mentionned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29776412/nodejs-http-request-returns-undefined) I was actually "clearing" my context with done() before the post data arrived. The solution is:

```
  var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
    res.statusCode.should.equal(200);

    res.on('data', function(data) {
      encryptedMessage = JSON.parse(data).message;
      encryptedMessage.should.not.equal(message);
      done();
    });
  });
```

In such a way that done() is only called when the data has been threated. Otherwise, mocha will not wait for the answer.